# Smallest genus for which the Hilbert Scheme of smooth curves is generically non-reduced

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $H_{d,g,3}$ denote the open subscheme of non-singular irreducible curves in $\text{Hilb}^{dn+1-g}_{\mathbf{P}^3}$. Mumford showed that when $g=24$ and $d= 14$, the open subscheme has an irreducible component that's generically non-reduced. Are there other examples for lower genera? In particular, what is the smallest genus for which one can find an irreducible, non-reduced component?

I did a quick(!) search of the literature and as far as I can tell, most of the papers that studied when $H_{d,g,3}$ was non-reduced did not study the smallest such genus.

Comment: My understanding is that Mumford found his famous example via an exhaustive computational study, so this seems unlikely unless there is some strange example with lower genus and absurdly high degree. Also, I have no idea if this is relevant, but $g = 24$ is almost the lowest genus for which we know $\mathcal M_g$ to be of general type. In a completely non-rigorous way, it somehow makes sense to me that these pathologies only start to arise when the moduli space starts to become severely inaccessible.

Comment: In [*Genre des courbes de l'espace projectif. II*](http://archive.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1982_4_15_3_401_0.pdf),  Gruson and Peskine give an example with $g=18$, $d=13$ (see Remarque p. 417). I don't know if this is the current world record.